# Аналог fgets для Golang

Tags: golang

Собственно, есть ли какой-либо аналог сишной функции fgets в Golang? В своём консольном приложении мне нужно считать пользовательский ввод до символа новой строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        // что-то пошло не так
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("вот что вы ввели в STDIN: " + string(bytes))
}
```